# como se habilitan los checkbox para poderlos likear en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-8.0

hola buenas tengo una duda que me gustaría que me ayudaran a a resolver estoy haciendo un programa en c# en visual studio 2022 y pasa que cuando creo un DataTable para mostrar unos datos el programa no me deja clickear unos de los checkbox y cuando me acerco dice **false**

**me podrían ayudar a decirme como puedo deshabilitar esto o que ago para que el usuario pueda seleccionar una opción**
[image: Dejo imagen para que vean de que hablo me refiero a donde dice marcar]

Comment: y ese datatable esta en???? wpf? winforms? uwp? asp?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica lo que te han preguntado en el comentario anterior, ya que la pregunta/respuesta debe ser útil no solo para ti, sino para los demás que tengan tu misma duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verifica si la columna Marcar es de tipo checkbox y tienes deshabilitado el readonly en sus propiedadespa para ello en tu datagrid presiona el icono de flecha que esta en la esquina superior derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues seleccionas editar columnas y te aparecera un menu como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las columnas de tipo checkbox tienen una palomita en su icono, verifica si tu columna es de tipo checkbox y tiene el comportamiento readonly en false

Comment: winforms o wpf??? o asp?? yo preguntaria eso primero ;)

Comment: muchas gracias @Luis Garcia la verdad nose que avia pasado pero cuando habilite el ReadOnly y lo aceptaba lo vlvia a poner en falso pero cambie el tipo de dato de la columna y luego lo volvi a poner a checkbox y al final si me dejo, muchas gracias de verdad